# Pie Graph Generator: Generates incorrect size/angle ONLY for some values

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, svg

I have made a very simple Pie Graph generator using Javascript & SVG graphics. You just enter the angle of the pie graph you want then click the button.

**My Problem:** It generates graphs that are too big for the angles 100 degrees, 180 degrees & many others. It does generate the correct pie for the angle 277. For an angle such as 180 which should be a half circle it shows a pie of 270 degrees for some reason.

**Whats wrong with my simple algorithm that leads to the wrong pie shapes/values?**

The JSFiddle is here *(for some reason the JSFiddle wont update but if you copy the HTML below it all works)*: http://jsfiddle.net/mabg3/1/

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
function createPieGraph()
{
   var angle    = parseInt(document.getElementById("angleVal").value, 10);
   var path     = document.getElementById("pie"); //document.createElement("path");
   var diameter = 200
   var rad      = diameter/2;
   var point    = resolveToPoint(angle, diameter);
   var d        = "M"+diameter+","+diameter+" L"+point.mX+","+point.mY+" A"+rad+","+rad+" "+determineDisplayType(angle)+" "+determineArcEnd(angle, diameter, rad)+" z";
   path.setAttribute("d", d);
}

function resolveToPoint( /*int*/ deg, /*int*/ diameter ) 
{
   var rad  = Math.PI * deg / 180;
   var r    = diameter / 2;
   var x    = r * Math.cos(rad);
   var y    = r * Math.sin(rad);
   var midX = diameter;
   var midY = diameter;

   if (deg <= 90)
   {
      console.log("1");
      x = midX + x;
      y = midY - y;
   }
   else if (deg <= 180)
   {
      console.log("2");
      x = midX + x;
      y = midY + y;
   }
   else if (deg <= 270)
   {
      console.log("3");
      x = midX - x;
      y = midY + y;
   }
   else if (deg <= 360)
   {
      console.log("4");
      x = midX - x;
      y = Math.abs(y);
   }

   return {mX: x, mY: y};
}

function determineDisplayType( /*int*/ deg )
{
   if (deg <= 90)
      return "0 0,0";
   else if (deg <= 180)
      return "0 1,0";
   else if (deg <= 270)
      return "0 1,0";
   else if (deg <= 360)
      return "1 1,1";

   return "0 0,0";
}

function determineArcEnd( /*int*/ deg, /*int*/ diameter, /*int*/ rad )
{
   if (deg >= 270)
      return ""+rad+","+diameter;

   return ""+diameter+","+rad;
}
    -->
    </script>
</head> 
<body>

    <svg id="main" width="400" height="400" style="background-color: red;">
        <path id="pie" fill="blue" stroke="white"></path>
    </svg>

    <input type="text" id="angleVal" value="Enter angle"></input>
    <input type="button" onclick="createPieGraph();" value="Show Pie Graph"></input>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/mabg3/11/

Firstly, the fiddle didn't work because your javascript was being wrapped, but your inline click handler was looking for a global function. I unwrapped it (see the drop box on the left), which isn't a good idea for real code, but solves the problem easily enough in this example.

I also made the code much shorter. Not sure what all those functions were for; the only flag that needs changing is the `large-arc` if the angle is more than half the circle. The `sweep` flag is constant because we always render in one orientation.

My code can be easily improved and generalised (you can handle negative and >360 angles differently, you can make the initial angle different, etc.), but it works well enough.